# Selecting a LinkText+Icon with phpunit selenium webdriver

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver, phpunit

So basically what I currently have is:

```
$search9 = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::linkText('Functies'));
$search9->click();
```

[image]

There's an icon linked after the text. ( The back arrow it has this class not sure if needed: )

```
class="icon-fixed-width icon-reply"
```

Problem: It won't click on ' Functies ' beside the icon is next to it.
How do I fix this so it will click on it?

**EDIT:**

Using:

```
 $search9 = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::className('first_parent'));
 $search9->click();
```

This will hover over this ' Functies ' but not actually click it ;/

Comment: Maybe add full html of the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it ><

```
    $search9 = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::className('icon-fixed-width'));
    $search9->click();
```

Going for the icon and not for the text worked.

Small workaround but yea works :D